# In Groovy is there a way to iterate over an array and find specific part of the string and store the entire part of the string in another variable

Tags: arrays, string, groovy, find, findall

Trying to find a way to iterate over an array, find or match some part of the string, if the string is matching the pattern copy the entire string in to a new variable, please find the below snippet

```
def sample_example_array = ["Sample\456" , "Sample231001", "xyz", "abc","Sample\123\Example1"]
// Need to iterate over the array by checking each element in the array look for String Example
// I tried find to find the first element matching the criteria
def new_string_sample_example = sample_example_array.find { sample_example_array.contains("Example1") }
println "Post Searching Matching the new variable is:" + new_string_sample_example
```

The result is **NULL**,

Could anyone kindly suggest how I could achieve this with Groovy

*Expected result is **Post Searching Matching the new variable is: Sample\123\Example1***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your code to:

```
def sample_example_array = ["Sample456" , "Sample231001", "xyz", "abc","Sample123Example1"]
// Need to iterate over the array by checking each element in the array look for String Example
// I tried find to find the first element matching the criteria
def new_string_sample_example = sample_example_array.find { it.contains("Example1") }
println "Post Searching Matching the new variable is:" + new_string_sample_example
```

it should work. In other words, change the content inside the `find { ... }` closure to refer the `it` variable which will be assigned each value in the array iteratively.

In groovy, for closures (i.e. the curlie blocks `{...}`) which take one argument (like this one) you can do either of:

```
[1,3,4].find { it < 4 }
// or
[1,3,4].find { n -> n < 4 }
```

which are equivalent.

Executing the fixed code above gives:

```
─➤ groovy solution.groovy
Post Searching Matching the new variable is:Sample123Example1
```

Comment: Thanks @Matias Bjarland